# AJAX ready state 4 and status 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX call (pure JavaScript) for storing an user in DB.

My java script file contains the following code:

```
var url="interfata_db.php";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        alert('ready state ' + xmlhttp.readyState + ' status ' + xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };   
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("tag=" + tag + "&name=" + nume + "&first_name=" + prenume + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + parola1);
```

In `interfata_db.php` I set the header:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

and I built the response that is returned as JSON:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

The problem is that when I make the AJAX call the status is 0 for readyState = 4.
In Chrome Developer Tool `interfata_db.php` appears to be cancelled.
[image: Chrome Developer Tool]

I want to mention also that the user is stored successfully if it doesn't exist already.

What should I do to get the status 200?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the full code on how you are calling this Ajax call. That is the issue.

Comment: basic debugging: have the onreadstatechange output what the state/status ARE. then you can at least start figuring out what's happening based on all the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not canceling the action that is causing the page to navigate away. You need to stop it with [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) or returning false to stop the default action.